# How do I run a serve as daemon on linux?

Tags: linux, daemon

I created a server using c++ and want to run this server as daemon on linux..
How do I do this?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to daemonize a process. It is quite common that server implementations provides a switch to daemonize it at startup.

If you do not wish to implement such a feature, command-line tools exists such as this one : http://software.clapper.org/daemonize/.

Answer (score 0):

I don't mean to sound condescending but did you try a google search, there is a heap of info on this out there, the first link I found: (http://www.enderunix.org/docs/eng/daemon.php)

You can use dup2() on Linux to make the FD's a bit easier to handle.

You may also want to look into using something like inetd to manage your server